# what are steps of creating new language for Composite CMS?

Tags: c1-cms

What are   main steps of creating another language (such as Persian )for composite CMS ?
i think i  should do these steps: 
1. I think i should add my language to list of cultures
 
2. there are files in localization which ends with"en-us.xml" I  should create their persian version with "fa-ir.xml"!??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to translate the administrative UI you can find guidance and tooling at http://docs.composite.net/Console/LocalizingConsole

If you wish to add another content language to your website you can find guidance at http://docs.composite.net/HTML/C1-Localization/Website-Languages and end-user help at http://users.composite.net/Pages/MultipleLanguages

Comment: @AmirRezaAsadi awesome! if you create the translation and want to share it with The Composite C1 community check http://community.composite.net/Get-involved/Translate-Composite-C1